# Regex returning extra, unwanted values upon searching for file names in URLS

Tags: python, regex

So, if I have a string `"http://www.images.com/place/folder/file_name.gif"`

I want a regex that returns:

```
"file_name.gif"
```

So far I have this (in python):

```
re.findall(r'([\w]+\.*?(gif|jpeg|jpg|png))',f)
```

but it returns

```
( "file_name.gif" , "gif" )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have two capturing groups, so the regex is returning two things. Make the second one a non-capturing group by changing it from `(...)` to `(?:...)` and the regex will return the single match.

Answer (score 1):

In your expression, you have *two capture groups*. Keep in mind that a set of `()` is a capture group. You want to combine the extension and the filename in one capture group, so that they are both returned try this one:

```
>>> exp = r'(\w+\.\w+)$'
>>> url = 'http://www.foo.com/hello.html'
>>> re.findall(exp, url)
['hello.html']
```

This expression is `one or more word characters, followed by a ., then one or more word characters`.

You can further enhance this by adding your specific extensions in place of the second `\w`. As long as you keep it in one set of `()`, you'll get the entire result of the expression as one match.

There is a basic flaw in that a valid URL like `http://www.example.com/this-file.gif` will fail:

```
>>> url = 'http://www.example.com/this-link.gif'
>>> re.findall(exp, url)
['link.gif']
```

Because `\w` does not include `-`, which is a valid file name. You can mitigate this by adding it in a character class:

```
>>> exp = r'([\w-]+\.\w+)$'
>>> re.findall(exp, url)
['this-link.gif']
```

This is rather in-elegant in that it doesn't match urls that have a fragment or a query string.

It will also be easily fooled if your URL doesn't end in a file name:

```
>>> url = 'http://www.example.com/this-is-a-valid-url'
>>> re.findall(exp, url)
[]
```

Since its specifically looking for a `.`, but then it will also be tripped up by this:

```
>>> url = 'http://www.example.com/this.is.a.url.gif'
>>> re.findall(exp, url)
['url.gif']
```

You could take that and build up on it, but as its difficult to predict the many combinations of possible URL endings beyond the very basic, it is recommended to use the existing tools:

```
>>> import os
>>> import urlparse
>>> os.path.basename(urlparse.urlsplit(url).path)
'this.is.a.url.gif'
```

In Python 3, use `urllib.parse`.

Comment: Because this is a question about regex :)

Comment: _"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."_ [Source](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: Maybe I should be clearer. This isn't about solving the problem of getting a file name. I know there are many simple ways to do that. This is about understanding how to use regex.

Comment: @AllTheTime - I expanded on my answer a bit to include the regular expression part.